# Make a selecbox(es) required based on another selectbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have product called initials like below in my test site

http://dev.mommyjewelry.com/initials/sideways-initial-necklace.html

Now if you go that page and select how many gold initials you will more select box appear below based on the selection. So If I select 2 initials I am display below 2 select boxes below where we have to select the letters of the initials

Now I am looking to make these 2 select boxes for instance in this example required. so If we click add to shopping cart button, display a pop up saying that these 2 select boxes are required. and prevent going to the shopping cart.

So again if I select how many gold initials as 3 then the 3 displayed select boxes are the ones I am looking to make in required.

I know when I have a textbox instead of select box I can use the below code

```
$("#product_form").submit(function(evt) {
    var target = $("#yellow-gold").val(); var target1 = $("#white-gold").val();
    if(target == "initial-0" && target1=="initial-0"){
      alert("You must select either White Gold or Yellow Gold Necklace.");
      evt.preventDefault();
    }else{
    var number_of_charms = $("#yellow-gold").attr("selectedIndex") + 0;
     var number_of_gold = $("#white-gold").attr("selectedIndex") + 0;
     var fields_not_empty = $(":text[name^=Product_Attribute]:visible[value]").length;
     if(number_of_charms >  fields_not_empty) {
          $(".error").show();
          alert("You left one or more required fields empty. Please check your selection above and adjust as needed.");
          evt.preventDefault();
     }else if(number_of_gold >  fields_not_empty) {
          $(".error").show();
          alert("You left one or more required fields empty. Please check your selection above and adjust as needed.");
          evt.preventDefault();
     }
    }
});
```

as you can see above from my above code that I am able to display the message when it a text box by using this line

```
var fields_not_empty = $(":text[name^=Product_Attribute]:visible[value]").length;
```

but how to use the same in case of a selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("div[id^='sideways-yellow']:visible select[name^=Product_Attribute] option:selected[value='select-letter']").length
```

This should get you the number of not selected options for the gold initial(Where the option value is `select-letter`)

If you need to get the white one, you can just change `sideways-yellow` to `sideways-white`

Sorry about the previous answer, I didn't realize I wasn't getting only the visible ones.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried but it does not work. You can see from the above page I have updated the code to below

Comment: Hmm where do post my update code I can't seem to do in comments